# PHP implementing interfaces, slash on some param qualifiers

Tags: php, oop

I've impemented a userDAO interface via

```
<?php
interface UserDAOInterface {

  public function insertData($model, $uid, CDbCommand $command);
  public function getData($key, CDbCommand $command);
  public function updateData($model, $uid, CDbCommand $command);
  public function deleteData($key, CDbCommand $command);
}
?>
```

and in each of the implementing classes, I auto-generated the implementing methods.  Thing is,
all the `CDbCommand` qualifiers all have a `\` in front of them.  What does this represent and why is it there?

Comment: where is the ``\``displayed exactly?

Comment: The slash simply says that you want to load the class from root namespace.

Comment: "Auto-generated" how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php 5.3 [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) were introduced.

A namespace is something like packages in other programming languages.

Previous the standard was to use `_` for namescapes. This led to classes like `Zend_Db_Something_Really_Long_That_Was_Super_Amazing` (you get the point).

With namespaces you can define this pretty fancy like

```
<?php

namespace Zend\Db\Something\Really\Long\That\Was\Super;

class Amazing{}
```

Then in other scripts you use the magic keyword `use` to import the namespace and then you could use `Amazing` as class name

If you are in a namespace however and you want to use a global Class, like php interfaces you need to use the `\` infront of them or use the magic keyword `use` just after the declartion of the namespace.

I recommend reading the docs about [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) to get more detailed info